# How do you bake a texture without parts of the texture disappearing?

Tags: texture-baking

I am fairly new to blender, and I am trying to bake multiple textures into one so that I can export it to a game engine. I followed tutorials, but I kept running into an issue where one texture would appear, then disappear, then another texture appears, than the first texture reappears, then disappears, and then the bake ends.[image: This is a picture of what I am trying to bake] This is the tutorial I was following, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MH7Xdol5erw&t=502s.
[image]

Comment: could you please pack the images and share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots I packed the images but I can't figure out how to share the .blend file, how do you do that.

Comment: or use this site: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots Thanks, I added it.

Comment: do you want to bake all the objects in one unique image? I've created an image called Bake, then in the Shader Editor I've created an Image Texture node for each material, loaded the image called Bake, kept these nodes selected, selected all the obejcts then pressed on the bake button, and it worked...

Comment: @moonboots I am trying to bake all of the textures into one image, so that I can export the model and texture to a game engine.

Comment: yes so have you tried to follow my method, and if so, is there something you didn't understand?

Comment: @moonboots I finally got it to work, I the only thing I did differently was that I was in object mode instead of edit mode, do you think that might have made any difference?

Comment: there must be something else that you were doing wrong because it seems to work fine in Edit mode as well, but maybe I miss something...

Comment: @moonboots That's weird. But, thanks for your help anyways.